# Connecting Spring boot data to a database with ssl verify-ca

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ssl-certificate

I want to join the Postgresql database over ssl, I tried to place the certificate files both in the resources folder and in any other folder.
I get this error java.io.IOException: extra data at the end.

When I connect using IDEA or pgAdmin everything is successful.

But when programmatically an error appears

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not read SSL key file D:\key\externalAPI\client-key.pem.
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractKeyManagerWrapper.getPrivateKey(SSLContextImpl.java:1696) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createClientPossession(X509Authentication.java:254) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:209) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.choosePossession(CertificateMessage.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1102) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:958) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:440) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.onConsumeFinished(Finished.java:1030) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.consume(Finished.java:893) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.example.dbconnection.DbConnectionApplication.main(DbConnectionApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: extra data at the end
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:428) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.wrap(DerValue.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.wrap(DerValue.java:315) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:87) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:236) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

application.yml settings

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  datasource:
    hikari.data-source-properties:
      ssl: true
      sslmode: verify-ca
      sslcert: D:\key\externalAPI\client-crt.pem
      sslkey: D:\key\externalAPI\client-key.pem
      sslrootcert: D:\key\externalAPI\db-cert.pem
      sslpassword: 1111
    url: jdbc:postgresql://00.000.00.0:5432/integration_db


    username: integration_api
    password: 1111
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

client-key.pem looks like

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAsiwBwzEhd2DLxCRpIUEHeBscwU4UJ3ZMRd7zWNOiPJIA8z8X
Q9mKiUjnMGS02AQuPDevwSroeXYV7w/twi7VPZvc96yXjct858NDzq/3XOkcWPr+
...
6fgph9GcCef4B7los0PfLJNbO+nLpgL9MG/TbMjlfi9FhiTik+jCi49JYq4=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I tried to place the files in the resources folder, but then the program could not find these files
I tried to set the files via the connection url

```
    url: jdbc:postgresql://00.000.00.0:5432/integration_db?ssl=true&sslmode=verify-ca&sslcert=D:\key\externalAPI\client-crt.pem&sslkey=D:\key\externalAPI\client-key.pem&sslrootcert=D:\key\externalAPI\db-cert.pem
```

but it didn't work

I try converting your PEM key to DER
like in
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2859

now i get this exeption

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not read SSL key file D:\key\externalAPI2\client-key.der.
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractKeyManagerWrapper.getPrivateKey(SSLContextImpl.java:1696) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createClientPossession(X509Authentication.java:254) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:209) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.choosePossession(CertificateMessage.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1102) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:958) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:440) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.onConsumeFinished(Finished.java:1030) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.consume(Finished.java:893) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.example.dbconnection.DbConnectionApplication.main(DbConnectionApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 1824
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:98) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:236) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

I guess something is wrong with the client-key file
i don't understand what

Comment: Are you sure the files are exactly as they were generated? Check whether some line endings were changed or maybe something was appended (e.g. a newline at the end of a file).

Comment: I checked. I tried to connect to the database using IDEA and PgAdmin and everything worked out. I used exactly the same files

Answer (score 0):

I am running in to this as well when using 'PGSimpleDataSource', for now converting my PEM cert to DER solves the problem:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in source.key -out outKey.key -nocrypt
```